# Trouble Benchmarking actix_web api with Criterion

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio, actix-web, rust-criterion

I have been trying to add benchmarking using the [Criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion) crate to my [actix_web](https://crates.io/crates/actix-web) application. I have been struggling to get it to work because the [AsyncExecutor](https://docs.rs/criterion/0.3.4/criterion/async_executor/trait.AsyncExecutor.html) trait is not implemented for [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) 0.2.x. I tried implementing the trait for the [actix_rt](https://crates.io/crates/actix-rt) runtime but ran into issues there as well, code below

```
impl AsyncExecutor for ActixRuntime {
    fn block_on<T>(&self, future: impl Future<Output=T>) -> T {
        self.rt.block_on(future)
    }
}

pub struct ActixRuntime {
    rt: actix_rt::Runtime,
}

impl ActixRuntime {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ActixRuntime {
            rt: actix_rt::Runtime::new().unwrap(),
        }
    }
}
```

this errors out because the block_on function for [actix_rt](https://crates.io/crates/actix-rt) (and [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio) 0.2.x) is has a signature of
`block_on(&mut self, ...) -> ... { ... }`
So I cannot implement the trait since the trait has an immutable reference.

Before I dig myself further into trying to make this work I want to ask if what I am attempting is possible. Is there a way to use [Criterion](https://crates.io/crates/criterion)  with [actix](https://crates.io/crates/actix-web)? Or is this impossible as of now? If it is not possible are there any other frameworks available or should I look at solutions outside the rust toolchain?

Thanks for any advice or help, links and examples welcome!

Cheers!

Comment: actix-rt 2.0's `block_on` takes `&self` [now after upgrading to tokio 1.0](https://github.com/actix/actix-net/pull/236). Is upgrading not an option?

Comment: If not, perhaps you can wrap `rt` in a `RefCell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actix-rt` v2's `block_on` method takes `&self` now [after upgrading to tokio 1.0](https://github.com/actix/actix-net/pull/236). Upgrading should fix your issue:

```
// pin your deps: https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1944
actix-rt = "=2.0.0-beta.2"
actix-web = "4.0.0-beta.1"
actix-service = "=2.0.0-beta.3"
```

If upgrading is not an option, you can use an interior mutability wrapper, such as `RefCell`:

```rust
impl AsyncExecutor for ActixRuntime {
    fn block_on<T>(&self, future: impl Future<Output=T>) -> T {
        self.rt.borrow_mut().block_on(future)
    }
}

pub struct ActixRuntime {
    rt: RefCell<actix_rt::Runtime>,
}

impl ActixRuntime {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        ActixRuntime {
            rt: RefCell::new(actix_rt::Runtime::new().unwrap())
        }
    }
```

Comment: axtix_rt 2.0 fixes the integration with Criterion but it apparently is not compatible with actix-web 3.3.2 (or any stable actix-web version as of this time)

Comment: If upgrading to v4.0-beta is causing dependency conflicts, you can [pin you dependencies](https://github.com/actix/actix-web/issues/1944)

Comment: I am probably going to wait for 4.x to be stable, Attempting to use RefCell doesn't work due to lifetime mismatch (compiler want's the future to have a static lifetime). But thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem like a good way to do this. There are no stable actix versions supporting actix_rt 2.0.x (though it would fix the mutability conflicts in the AsyncExecutor). As of right now actix-web 4.0.x is in beta and too unstable for my existing application (causes all sorts of issues when used). For now I will wait until actix-web 4.0.0 is released and stable to implement benchmarks for my api.